# How can I wrap element content to the next line, starting from the first of its container using flex or other CSS properties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flexbox, flex4

i want to wrap the content of an element to the next line and it should start from the first of its container.

i need something like this picture. is it possible to achieve this with flex ?? how about other CSS properties ?

```html
<html>
  <style>
    .container {display: flex}
    .item1 {color: red}
    .item2 {float: left}
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="item1"> hi</div>
      <div class="item2"> hello this is a long line that should beark to the next lineeeee. </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Please add your code to the question, as text and not image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<html>
  <style>
    .container {width: 20vw;}
    .item1 {color: red; float: left}
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <span class="item1"> hi</span>
      <span class="item2"> hello this is a long line that should beark to the next lineeeee. </span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I added `width: 20vw` only to the container to show that it works. Without that, the content would not be long enough to break.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i should use div instead of span... also i have nested divs in my main code and it doesn't work in that case.

Comment: Furthermore, floats do not work within a flex container. I'm searching for alternative ways to achieve my desired layout using flex.

Comment: Using div instead of span would be no problem when using the correct style. However note that flexbox is not designed for traditional floating layouts. Maybe it's worth considering using something else. You could for example use another container inside your flex-container to be able to use float.

Comment: thank you so much. adding another container solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try CSS property called `float:right`,
I think this will give you the result you want.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Comment: i tried it but it didn't work. if you resize my code snippet screen you can see that.

Comment: please, write this app on codesandbox so I can access it
I will fix it and discuss it with u.